# Javascript scroll navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone can help me. Here is my project: http://jsfiddle.net/oz7bgL5v/8/

```
adjustNav: function(self, $parent) {
    self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
    $(".next").click();
    $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);                     
}
```

This works when scrolling down but not when scrolling up.

I just need to go back in pagination navigation (click "previous" button) when scrolling up (You intuitively can understand what I mean when you see my project.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect going to 'previous' when scrolling up you need to keep track of the previous scroll location when you handle scrolling. Please see how I did it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x74w3tcs/

Then your adjustNav function can look like this:

```
adjustNav: function(self, $parent, direction) {
    self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);

    $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass); 

    if (direction === 'up') {
        $(".prev").click();
    }   
    else {
        $(".next").click();
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. You have done me a great help. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome :) In your original code, the scroll event handler was just setting a flag which was checked later to call a function that adjusts the nav, when you can just call the function from the event handler (I changed this in my fiddle). Also there is probably a better way to handle checking if document height changes than setting an interval to check every 250ms; maybe .resize() will do what you want? https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :(
Was trying from start.

Comment: Ah, you can click the check mark under the up/down arrows to accept the answer. Up vote is a different thing :)